# Temporary table delete row

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why I can't delete row from temporary table?

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
    (
    Id int,
    ImieNazwisko varchar(200),
    Pesel varchar(200),
    Kod varchar(200)
    )

DELETE FROM @tbl2 tblT WHERE tblT
SELECT * FROM @tbl2
```

also this doesn`t work:

```
DELETE FROM @tbl2 WHERE @tbl2.Id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete from a temprorary table. It's just your syntax seems wrong.

Try this:

```
--drop table #temptable 
create table #temptable (Id int)
insert into #temptable 
select 1 union
select 2 union 
select 3 

delete from #temptable 
where Id =2

select Id from #temptable
```

Comment: working correct but I don`t understand why my example doesn`t work.

Comment: It's a syntax issue. Glad that it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
    (
    Id int,
    ImieNazwisko varchar(200),
    Pesel varchar(200),
    Kod varchar(200)
    )

DELETE FROM @tbl2 tblT WHERE tblT.ID  = 1  --- for single row delete 
SELECT * FROM @tbl2
```

--from your case you want to delete all data from table i think it should be

```
delete from @tbl2 -- only
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE T (SELECT * FROM @tbl2) T WHERE T.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists Locations;
Create temporary table Locations
SELECT au_lname, au_fname, 
CASE 
WHEN state = "CA" or state = "AZ" THEN "west side"
WHEN state = "UT" or state = "MI" or state = "TN" THEN "mid US"
ELSE "east side"
END AS LocationInTheUS 
FROM authors
order by LocationInTheUS desc;
delete from Locations where au_lname = " ";
select * from Locations;
```